# What are the main differences -- in meditation practice and discipline -- between different schools of Theravada?

Tags: theravada, practice

Wikipedia lists schools in this section ...

> [Schools of Buddhism (Theravāda subschools)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schools_of_Buddhism#Therav%C4%81da_subschools)

... but, those pages which describe each school focus on **doctrine or philosophical aspects** (and don't always emphasise the differences with other subschools).

I am interested in aspects that have more to do with **practice and disciplines**, e.g.:

- What are the main differences in how monastic life is led in each of these subschools?
- What does meditation practice focus on and how does that change from one school to the other?

For instance: I know that in the teaching of [Mahasi Sayadaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahasi_Sayadaw) there is an emphasis on verbalising whatever is taking place in the present moment; whereas [Ajahn Chah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajahn_Chah) focuses on "opening the heart". I expect other subschools to neglect walking meditation of discourage verbalisation, others not to allow nuns, etc.

---

Edit -- 
an answer mentioned that Wikipedia also has another page ...

> [Theravada (Monastic orders within Theravāda)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theravada#Monastic_orders_within_Therav%C4%81da)

... which discusses *nikayas* rather than *subschools* and so which is more pertinent to my question. Unfortunately, those pages too don't discuss, detail, nor compare, the discipline and meditation practice.

Answer (score 1):

The question quoted [Theravāda subschools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schools_of_Buddhism#Therav%C4%81da_subschools) on Wikipedia.

There's another list on Wikipedia -- i.e. [Monastic orders within Theravāda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theravada#Monastic_orders_within_Therav%C4%81da) -- that identifies specific characteristics of various "monastic nikayas", which is part of what the question is asking about.

Comment: Unfortunately, both that section of Wikipedia and the pages linked by it do not go into any detail about practice and discipline.